# executing a c file on Zynq through ethernet?

Tags: fpga, ethernet, zynq

I have designed a firmware on zedboard and I want to use some language(say C) to write the program for my firmware and transfer this file through Ethernet and then compile -> execute it.

I will be grateful, if someone can help with this issue!

Thank you in advance for your kind help!!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run some flavor of Linux on your Zedboard, then you can interact with it and send files to it over ethernet. This is extremely convenient.

Xilinx supports Petalinux, which will enable you to connect to your board over ethernet using ssh.

If your Linux installation is complete enough, you can run the C compiler on the zedboard. For example, you can install Ubuntu and install gcc that way.

I find it easier to run a cross compiler on my desktop machine or a server and develop and compile the files there and send the resulting executables to the Zedboard.

In the Connectal project (http://www.connectal.org) we compile hardware and software on a development machine, link the bitstream into the application executable, and program the logic when the application runs. This ensures that the application and firmware stay in sync.

We have a web-hosted development environment that enables you to build any open source project using the Connectal framework and run it on a local zedboard, without installing any development tools.

Comment: Dear Jamey, Many Thanks for your answer. Even I figured out the way you suggest here is works well in my case. I am using a SDK to design a custom program that could read my file and execute it. so i am sending both bit files, .elf and text file(to be read by .elf file) file using ssh and excuting it directly on zedboard.